# Unable to start Anaconda Navigator in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

Stackoverflow community, I installed Anaconda on my PC but I am unable to launch the Anaconda Navigator.

I have already read some previous questions about this type of problem, and I even reinstalled it, but I am still not able to fix the problem. Can someone give me a hand? Many thanks.

[image: Screenshot of CMD prompt]

Comment: what error you are encountering ? what is the RAM of your PC ?

Comment: Anaconda Navigator installed but fails to start. Also, Jupyter Notebook fails to start either. RAM = 4 GB. No error comes on screen, they just do not open.

Comment: Anaconda is bit memory intensive application. It is good to have 8gb RAM. for 4gb RAM it will definitely work you need to wait for some long time(some times more than 10 mins) for the application to launch.

Comment: can you try to launch anaconda navigator from your anaconda command prompt and see if you see any error message in the terminal?

Comment: Hello. The problem was solved. I just uninstalled Anaconda2 and installed Anaconda3 instead. All the problems are gone. Thank you very much for the reply.